# Face detection using Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I was searching for WORA solutions for my app and wondered if Face detection and landmarking can be done using Codename One.

If not, is Xamarin or React Native the way to go?

Comment: Didn't find any info about Codename One face detection. But I can recommend you Xamarin. [Here](https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-facial-recognition-to-your-mobile-apps/) info about Xamarin face recognition

Comment: Dima that uses a webservice request for face detection which is pretty lame

Comment: @Dima The problem I face with Xamarin is that the app size is drastically more than if it were developed natively. That's a big turn off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed native API's like Open CV into Codename One thru native interfaces which we describe in the developer guide [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

You can probably also wrap one of the many face detection libraries with a cn1lib. I haven't tried to do this myself and have no experience with this directly but if you get stuck just ask a specific question and we're here to help.

Comment: In that case, I'll be asking and looking forward to many questions be answered by you because I myself barely know what I am doing. Please guide me to any introductory material I might need when I start with CN1. Thanks